# Points on a graph falling out of a curve

Tags: python, plot

[image]

I have to check whether a point is within an ellipse with semiaxes a and b. I generated a list of tuples (dots) and then generated another list of tuples (dotsin) where I only keep those points that are within an ellipse.

However, when generated, some points fall out of the ellipse. Is this error accumulation trough calculations, and if so how do I improve on this so the dots do not fall out of the curve?

Do note that I am a bit rusty in python and some things are not obvious for me.
Thanks in advance!

```
    dots=[(random.uniform(-a,a),random.uniform(-b,b)) for i in range(1000)]#;dots
    dotsin=[(x,y) for x,y in dots if (x**2 + y**2)<((a*cos(atan(y/x)))**2 + (b*sin(atan(y/x)))**2)]#;dotsin
    plt.scatter([x[0] for x in dotsin],[y[1] for y in dotsin])
    plt.grid()
```

Comment: The image is under the "Enter image description here", if you are confused, as the page will not allow me to post pictures yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition `(x**2 + y**2)<((a*cos(atan(y/x)))**2 + (b*sin(atan(y/x)))**2)` is equivalent to `(x**2 + y**2)**2 < (a*x) ** 2 + (b*y) ** 2`. This is not an equation of ellipse. An equation of ellipse is `(x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 < 1`.

```
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, atan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
a = 3
b = 2
n = 1000
dots=[(random.uniform(-a,a),random.uniform(-b,b)) for i in range(n)]#;dots
dotsin=[(x,y) for x,y in dots if (x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 < 1]#;dotsin
plt.scatter([x[0] for x in dotsin],[y[1] for y in dotsin])
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
plt.plot(a*np.cos(phi), b*np.sin(phi))
plt.grid()
```

[image: ellips]

Comment: I feel pretty damn foolish now, guess next time I should proof-read my code. Thanks for showing me the error of my ways.

Comment: If the answer answers your question, you can accept (and, possible, upvote) it by clicking on checkmark (and, possibly, buttom "up") to the left of it.